# "TypeError: the JSON object must be str, not 'bytes'" reading JSON in Python 3.5

Tags: python, json, python-2.7, python-3.5

I want to run the following code, first written for Python 2.7, which now I want to run for python3.5.
The following is my code:

```
import json
import glob

read_files = glob.glob("*.json")
output_list = []

for f in read_files:
    with open(f, "r") as infile:
       output_list.append(json.load(infile))

with open("merged_file.json", "wb") as outfile:
    json.dump(output_list, outfile)
```

But it keeps giving the following error :

```
         raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from 
None
 json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

What is the difference between `json.load` and `json.loads` and how can I make sure which one to use when ?

Comment: Remove the binary mode in your `open` (`"rb"` -> `"r"`). I have no idea why you even put that in there.

Comment: You could read a file as a string instead of in binary mode

Answer (score 1):

Change your `open(f, "rb")` to `open(f, "r")`. The rb flag is for reading as bytes.

Comment: When I change that , it is followed by this error:    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

Comment: use json.loads to load string